# Как сделать итог в Qreport?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, хотел бы спросить, в отчете Qreport выводится столбец количество, как сделать что-то вроде графы ИТОГО по этому столбцу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как в новых, а в очень-очень-старых нужно было в графическом конструкторе:

В верстку печатной страницы отчета добавить элемент "GroupHeader", закрепить за ней запрос и поле, по которому идет группировка (её можно сделать узкой).

После добавить "GroupFotter" группы, а в ней вставить мемо-поле, в котором прописать что-то вида "=SUM(Query1.val)"

Вместо них можно использовать "ReportHeader" и "ReportFooter".

P.S. Пишу по памяти, было очень давно. Надеюсь пригодилось.